# If else statement in SQL Server function won't compile

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to see if a date occurs within the last year, and if so, then increase a value by 1. So I tried the following, but it returns the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure IsComplete, Line 41 [Batch Start Line 7]
>   Incorrect syntax near '@compliant'.

Code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[IsComplete] (@input VARCHAR(9))
RETURNS CHAR(1)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @idnum VARCHAR(9)
    DECLARE @complete CHAR
    DECLARE @cert int
    DECLARE @compliant int

    SET @idnum = SUBSTRING(@input, 0, 9)
    SET @compliant = 0

    SET @cert = (SELECT DATEDIFF(month, CertifiedDate, GETDATE()) 
                 FROM Profile 
                 WHERE IDNumber = @idnum)

    BEGIN
        IF @cert > 11
        BEGIN
            @compliant = @compliant + 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            -- do nothing
        END
    END 

    RETURN @complete
END
```

Seems simple, but I just can't get this to work, in that it gives errors and won't compile. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: what mean doesnt work? error ?? wrong result? and where is your funciton declaration?

Comment: You cant have an empty block. Remove the ELSE BEGIN END

Comment: Also missing a datatype for the compliant variable. Probably need to initialise it to a suitable value too, as if it starts null you may get unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't add everything from the code, as I was trying to keep the question simple. I've edited to add it all in.

Comment: "Can't get it work" won't help us help you.  Tell us not work how???  Can't create Function??  Run but no result??  Run but wrong result???

Comment: You don't have a datatype defined for @compliant. Is that supposed to be an int? And you don't have the scale defined on complete.

Comment: @ Eric, updated. It won't run in that I receive the following error - Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure IsComplete, Line 41 [Batch Start Line 7]
Incorrect syntax near '@compliant'.

Comment: @SeanLange compliant is an int. I've fixed it. I didn't have one for complete, but I put in CHAR(1) and still get the same error - Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure IsComplete, Line 41 [Batch Start Line 7]
Incorrect syntax near 'compliant'.

Comment: @sharcfinz `SET @compliant = @compliant + 1`  You are missing `SET`.  Also remove the whole `ELSE` section.  You cannot have an empty `ELSE`.

Comment: Also, you're **returning** `@complete` -but you **never assign anything** to it! ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error, in line 25 of the function, you have just forget to add `SET`. So change it as below:

```
SET @compliant = @compliant + 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Apply the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle):

```
SET @compliant = @compliant + 
    (SELECT
      case when DATEDIFF(month, CertifiedDate, GETDATE()) > 11 then 1 else 0 end
     FROM Profile
     WHERE IDNumber = @idnum)
```

Comment: what is KISS here?

Comment: @Juan edited to add link to KISS. I means "Keep it Simple". You have waaay too much code; it can be done in 1 statement (as I have shown)

Comment: Ahh, ok. I'm all new to this! But I get an error when I try to compile - Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure IsComplete, Line 32 [Batch Start Line 7]
Incorrect syntax near '@compliant'.

Comment: The KISS principle is, IMHO, one of the top three principles, especially for programmers.

Comment: @Bohemian What's the second S??

Comment: @zohar what are the other two? :)

Comment: @Bohemian for programmers or in general?

Comment: Let's take this to the next level. Now that we have shown the OP how to do this in a single query go one more and turn this scalar function into a table valued function. It will perform better and be more flexible.

Comment: Well, let's do programmers, then. [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and don't reinvent the wheel. in most cases, no matter what problem you have, someone have already solved it, and posted in on stackoverflow :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `Else` clause is empty, and SQL doesn't like empty clauses.

Just remove the whole 'Else' section (as it's doing nothing), and your query should compile :)

Comment: Did that, but I got the following error - Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure IsComplete, Line 35 [Batch Start Line 7]
Incorrect syntax near '@compliant'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure IsComplete, Line 46 [Batch Start Line 7]
Incorrect syntax near 'END'.

Comment: @sharcfinz Did you remove the accompanying `BEGIN ... END` code as well?

Comment: I did, but receive part of the error still - Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure IsComplete, Line 41 [Batch Start Line 7]
Incorrect syntax near '@compliant'.

Answer (score 0):

**Try following query:**

```
USE [CDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[IsComplete] (@input VARCHAR(9))
RETURNS CHAR(1)

AS BEGIN
DECLARE @idnum VARCHAR(9)
DECLARE @complete CHAR
DECLARE @cert int
DECLARE @compliant int

SET @idnum = SUBSTRING(@input, 0, 9)
SET @compliant = 0

SET @cert = (SELECT DATEDIFF(month, CertifiedDate, GETDATE()) FROM Profile WHERE IDNumber = @idnum)

BEGIN
    IF @cert > 11
        BEGIN
            SET @compliant = @compliant + 1
        END
    --ELSE
    --    BEGIN
    --        -- do nothing
    --    END
END 

RETURN @complete

END
```

**Explanation:**

- I did only 2 small changes with your query:

  1. Added `SET` to the line `@compliant = @compliant + 1`
  2. Commented unwanted `ELSE` block.
- You can obviously simplify your logic later if you want. Though, it's better to fix the error first.

See if it works.

Comment: @sharcfinz - I commented your `ELSE` block to fix error and one small change. are you looking to add some more logic in `ELSE`? Check the query, if it works for you.